# Is it possible to close windows from App Exposé

Tags: mission-control, expose

I have too many Finder windows open. It's a mess!

First, I need to take stock of everything I have open, so I activate App Exposé (aka Mission Control Application Windows) via <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>. App Exposé shows me I have my Trash open in five different windows. I definitely want to close those!

Unfortunately, while App Exposé makes it easy to see what windows I have open, actually closing them is tedious! I need to individually click each window (which brings it to the front, but deactivates App Exposé), click the red close button (or use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>), then re-activate App Exposé and repeat!

Is there a quicker way to close windows from App Exposé?

Comment: I know Exposé got renamed to Mission Control a decade ago, but the "Application Windows" view seems to still be called App Exposé in several places, such as the Touchpad Prefpane, so that's the term I went with.

Comment: No, you cannot close a window while App Exposé is active as its purpose is to show the individual windows of a given application for you to choose from among the target application's windows.

Answer (score -1):

Since you can't close the windows thru Mission Control you can just use the Finder to close the windows.  The Finder windows that are open can be easily closed by clicking on the finder in the dock. That will bring all Finder windows to the front, one after another. Then all you have to do is click on the red dot in the left upper corner of each window.

Comment: I'm not trying to close all the Finder windows, I'm trying to close specific ones. And I can't tell *which* ones except from the App Exposé view. :(

Comment: I know.  But one comment said you couldn't do that.  So what are you left with?  Thats where my answer comes in.

Comment: (Just to be clear, I'm not the one who downvoted you, thank you for trying to help.)

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for clarifying about the downvote.